# Should I define all (potential) properties of the base class methods in the constructor in a class? It works without

Tags: javascript, typescript

If my base class contains this portion of code:

```
export default class OnScreenObject {
  constructor({ xPosition, yPosition }) {
    this.xPosition = xPosition;
    this.yPosition = yPosition;
  }

  draw() {
    this.ctx.translate(
      this.xPosition + this.width / 2,
      this.yPosition + this.height / 2,
    );
  }
```

and my sub class constructor contains this portion of code:

```
export default class Zombie extends OnScreenObject {
  constructor({ xPosition, yPosition }) {
    super({ xPosition, yPosition });
    this.width = 15;
    this.height = 15;
  }
```

Then the draw function works BUT the typescript checker (i am using JS, not typescript!) in VS Code says:

```
Property 'width' does not exist on type 'OnScreenObject'.
```

which makes sense.

Is what I have done bad coding, am I confused on some issues, or is typescript being pedantic?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems the **OnScreenObject** class misses declaration of needed properties (**x/yPosition**, **width**, **height**). It seems that adding declaration should fix the problem.

[Check on playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20OnScreenObject%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20protected%20xPosition%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20protected%20yPosition%3A%20number%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20protected%20width%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20protected%20height%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%7B%20xPosition%2C%20yPosition%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.xPosition%20%3D%20xPosition%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.yPosition%20%3D%20yPosition%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20draw()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F...%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Zombie%20extends%20OnScreenObject%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%7B%20xPosition%2C%20yPosition%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super(%7B%20xPosition%2C%20yPosition%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.width%20%3D%2015%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.height%20%3D%2015%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

```
class OnScreenObject {

  protected xPosition: number;
  protected yPosition: number; 
  protected width: number;
  protected height: number;

  constructor({ xPosition, yPosition }) {
    this.xPosition = xPosition;
    this.yPosition = yPosition;
  }

  draw() {
    //...
  }
}

class Zombie extends OnScreenObject {

  constructor({ xPosition, yPosition }) {
    super({ xPosition, yPosition });
    this.width = 15;
    this.height = 15;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how about in JS not typescript? If I were to add 'this.width = null; this.height = null;' to the base constructor would this somehow make my code better? It would get rid of the error, but I am struggling to get my head around what this would mean!

Comment: @Sumomo, if you work with pure JS, then, probably, you don't need the TS compiler at all. Consider the option to disable it for specific files or for the whole project, if no TS features are used.

Comment: Would you define width and height as null on the base class when using JS? The typescript error has made me question what I am doing, it does seem to make logical sense to do this, but why does it not give an error if I do not? What is best practice?

Comment: In my opinion, it's not so important to set null/some other values to the properties, before they are actually used. I would say it depends on the way your application is built, whether your components have some default size or not (if they have, then it might be a good idea to set it at the beginning and not resetting it each time default size should be used). So as long as my applications work without some data set to the properties, I'm ok with that. By the way, in my opinion there is no big difference between null and undefined (both values are not numbers, so both might cause errors).